# Allow global scope to let variable from imported Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I have JS file import.js (simplified):

```
let foo;

function fooBar () {

foo = bar;

}

window.onload = () => {
fooBar()
}
```

In my html file I have:

```
<script src=import.js type=module></script>
```

When I open the html file, at the console:

```
foo;
ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

I understand that this is due to imported modules only given lexical scoping - but what is the best way to allow imported `let
/const` variables scope on the window/global, so that I can access it at the the window console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `type="module"` and it works. You weren't exporting anything, but you were  treating `import.js` as something which exported a module. Just use it as you would any other script:

```
<script src="import.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using `<script type="module">`, you can use `import` and `export` syntax, and transfer what you need, for example:

```
<script type="module">
  import obj from './import.js';
  // do stuff with obj.foo
</script>
```

while `import.js` exports an object to which you assign a `foo` property:

```
const exportObj = {};
function fooBar () {
  exportObj.foo = bar;
}
window.onload = () => {
  fooBar()
}
export default exportObj;
```

That said, since it's populated *asynchoronusly*, you might consider exporting a Promise instead:

```
<script type="module">
  import fooProm from './import.js';
  fooProm.then((foo) => {
    // do stuff with foo
  });
</script>
```

and

```
let foo;
function fooBar () {
  foo = bar;
}
export default new Promise((resolve) => {
  window.onload = () => {
    fooBar();
    resolve(foo);
  }
});
```

(though, ideally, `foo` wouldn't get reassigned at all in the lower code)